# Laravel - Render html passed by an associative array

Tags: html, arrays, json, laravel

I've been struggling with this for a few days.

I have an associative array, which I want to loop in my view. It works great when looping to create a table, for example.

The thing is, in another view, I am going to need to include some HTML (a button) in the array, that I am going to pass to the view as a JSON. I've tried it like this and it, no success.

```
$datacol[] = array(
'button' => '<a href="tasks/details/{{ $task->id }}" class="btn btn-sm">
<i class="bookmark big icon" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Task Details"></i></a>',
'id' => $task->id,
'task_type' => (DB::table('tasktypes')->where('id','=', $task->task_type_id)->value('task_type')),
'related_block' => (DB::table('chapters')->where('id','=', $task->related_block)->value('description')),
'assigned_to' => (DB::table('users')->where('id','=', $task->assigned_to)->value('display_name')),
'time' => (DB::table('task_interactions')->where('task_id','=', $task->id)->pluck('task_time')->sum()),
'start_date' => (DB::table('task_interactions')->where('task_id','=', $task->id)->where('status','=','In Progress')->pluck('created_at')->first()),
'end_date' => (DB::table('task_interactions')->where('task_id','=', $task->id)->where('status','=','Finished')->pluck('created_at')->first()),
'status' => (DB::table('tasks')->where('id','=', $task->id)->value('status')),
'comments' => (DB::table('tasks')->where('id','=', $task->id)->value('comments'))
);
```

Does anyone knows a way of passing HTML inside the array and make sure that the array is rendered in the view.

```
<tbody>
@foreach($datacol as $d)
<tr>
<td>{{ $d['button'] }}</td>
<td>{{ $d['id'] }}</td>
<td>{{ $d['task_type'] }} - {{ $d['related_block'] }}</td>
<td>{{ $d['assigned_to'] }}</td>
<td>{{ $d['time'] }}</td>
<td>{{ $d['start_date'] }}</td>
<td>{{ $d['end_date'] }}</td>
<td>{{ $d['status'] }}</td>
<td>{{ $d['comments'] }}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
</tbody>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What error did you get when you try the example code?

Comment: if i loop to create a table, i see the code as it is in the array

Comment: Your example code is from controller or view? What's the point you want to do? Please be clear asking question.

Comment: Then take the markup out of the PHP code as I've shown in my answer. (Or, decode it like @btl says, but keep in mind this is not a good strategy)

Comment: I was going to answer your question, but I see you are downvoting them, good luck

Comment: I don't see any need to pre-render button for view , you are doing it wrong just pass data to view

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the answer I posted if the data in question is trusted. There is a reason it is a blade feature after all.

Answer (score 1):

Change your array like this you need to give proper html string for button since it will not further parsed by blade. In href you are using blade ({{}}) to append $task->id, That's why it will not append proper id to the url. you need to use (.) to concatenate id to url.

```
$datacol[] = array(
     'button' => '<a href="tasks/details/'.$task->id.'" class="btn btn-sm">
<i class="bookmark big icon" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Task Details"></i></a>',
    'id' => $task->id,
// other stuff 
);
```

And then in view render button using {!! $html !!}

```
<tbody>
@foreach($datacol as $d)
<tr>
<td>{!!$d['button'] !!}</td>
<td>{{ $d['id'] }}</td>
<td>{{ $d['task_type'] }} - {{ $d['related_block'] }}</td>
<td>{{ $d['assigned_to'] }}</td>
<td>{{ $d['time'] }}</td>
<td>{{ $d['start_date'] }}</td>
<td>{{ $d['end_date'] }}</td>
<td>{{ $d['status'] }}</td>
<td>{{ $d['comments'] }}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
</tbody>
```

I hope it will help :)

Comment: Tkx for your help. i've tried your solution but i have a problem with HTML special characters, the variable is not passed as an id, in any of the examples i've tried. another thing is, the portion /tasks of the link is doubled when i go over the button. i'll study this a litle more and get back to you

Answer (score 0):

Remove the button key-value pair completely from the PHP code and render the markup in the view.

You can generate the `<a>` tag in the view, only using the id you passed (`{{ $id }}`):

```
<a href="tasks/details/{{ $id }}" class="btn btn-sm">
<i class="bookmark big icon" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Task Details"></i></a>
```

No need to mix HTML in your PHP code (considering you're using Laravel, which completely isolates the view from other code).

Comment: Please explain the downvote. This is a perfectly valid and correct answer.

Comment: Hi, tkx for your help. It works with a table, but if i try to pass the button in a json  (wich i'll need in the future) , to create a datatable, it won't work, bacause the HTML will not be rendered correctly.

Comment: What do you mean by *pass the button in a JSON*? Instead of HTML (i.e. view), you need to pass *data*, so that only the *view* can decide how to render it. If you send markup from your controller's code to the *view*, then the *view* won't have any options. What if in the future you want to use other tags instead of `a`/`i`, say `button`? You'll need to poke into the controller, not the view. Or, worse -what if you want to use another view with the same controller? You'll practically be unable. ***In summary**: delegate rendering to the **view** and keep the controller simple. without markup.*

Comment: @AI.G.  - I get what you are saying, and i've been doing it like that. But the thing is that i want to make table more dinamic, using datatables, to filter data in the view, and i want to keep the links in the table, to access more detailed information on each task (table line). That's why i want to pass the button in JSON. I am open to suggestions, maybe there are simpler ways to do what i want. Thanks

Comment: *I want to make table more dynamic, using datatables, to filter data in the view, and I want to keep the links in the table, to access more detailed information on each task* - but the `<button>` tag doesn't bring any new information. All the data from DB is already sent to the view via the other props.